# add numeric value with different color in radar labels

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, radar-chart, chart.js3

I am new to chart.js. i need help in adding a numeric value to radar chart point labels with different color. eg [radar label with styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oghrF.png)

1. labels color should be in black.
2. numeric value should be in a different predefined color(eg blue).

```js
new Chart('radar-chart', {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ['mon 30', 'tue 40', 'thurs 25', 'fri 45', 'sat 67', 'sun 50'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55],
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      r: {
        pointLabels: {
          color: 'black',
          font: {
            size: 20,
            style: 'italic'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart"></canvas>
```

the values near the labels in vertex should be in a predefined color(eg blue) -like the one attached in image.

please feel free to give a different approach to achieve this requirement. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/charts/Radar.js)

Comment: i could able plot a radar chart. i want add a numeric value to the extreme radar labels with different color ( like the one in image i attached). i am not sure it could be customizable in chart.js

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproducible code or any sandox link?

Comment: i have added a code snipet fr an example in the question itself. please check it. thanks fr the help in advance.